# Interpreting octal dump without options

Tags: od

```
$ echo "hello" | od
0000000 062550 066154 005157
0000006
```

I know that the first column represents the byte offset. But I don't see how the other numbers are formed. According to `man` the above should be "octal bytes". However the option `-b` is supposed to "select octal bytes" as well and it prints something different:

```
$echo "hello" | od -b
0000000 150 145 154 154 157 012
0000006
```

EDIT: This is by the way what I would expect to appear i.e. the ascii values of all characters in 'hello\n' as what I would expect to be called "octal bytes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`od` doesn't show bytes by default, it shows words in octal. This may not quite be intuitive, but don't forget `od` is a *very* old command :-) I'll use a somewhat simpler example than you did:

```
$ echo -en '\01\02' | od
0000000 001001
0000002
```

As Intel uses a [*little-endian* architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), the bytes `\01\02` are interpreted as `00000010 00000001` in binary.

As octal digits each represent 3 bits, we can group that number like this:

```
(0)(000)(001)(000)(000)(001)
```

So the octal representation of those 2 bytes is:

```
001001
```

For day to day use this is pretty useless; perhaps back in the day it was handy for manually debugging memory dumps :-)

Your `hello\n` example is:

```
h = 01101000
e = 01100101
l = 01101100
l = 01101100
o = 01101111
\n= 00001010
```

It's a bit more complicated now, because octal digits represent 3 bits, but bytes are 8 bits; so padding is added :-( The result symbollicaly is:

```
PehPllP\no
```

Remember, each set of 2 bytes is swapped due to the endianness. The *P* is a padding of 2 bits. The result in octal is (using a slash as separator):

```
00/01100101/01101000/00/01101100/01101100/00/00001010/01101111
```

Now in octal groups of 3 bits:

```
000 110 010 101 101 000 000 110 110 001 101 100 000 000 101 001 101 111
```

Translated into octal digits:

```
062550066154005157
```

This matches your result.

In conclusion you've probably learnt that `od` without options is worse than useless :-)

Comment: Can you explain to me why this swap of bytes happens in little endianness? Also I don't understand why the padding is added only every two bytes. It would be more intuitive for me if there was one bit of padding for each byte.

Comment: The padding is added for every *word*, where a word consists of two bytes. Little endian means that the least significant byte comes first, so you calculate the real value of a word you have to multiply the second byte by 256 and then add the first byte. Multiplying by 256 is the same as shifting the bits to the left 8 positions, so the result is the same as swapping the bytes. I'm sure the wikipedia link can explain it better than I can.

Comment: Okay I think I understood it a lot better now. Another question: Why does `\01\02` equal to two bytes only and `0101` equal to four bytes? (the latter one makes sense to me)

Comment: The `\01` is octal notation for one byte, it can range from `\0` to `\0377`. I don't know why you think `0101` is equal to four bytes though.

Comment: I thought because of ASCII code? 1 byte = 1 char?

Comment: Only if it's a string, and not a number. That wasn't clear from your comment.